# Next.js live price updates from GetServerSideProps props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

I'am trying to fetch live price of bitcoin from CoinGecko. I have async GetServerSideProps in index.js that works as intended, and i am passing return props to `<Home />` further to `<Main />` component, and finally to `<Calculatorbuy />` component. Everything works, but i'm getting the price only once on the start. What is the best way to get live price updates? i tried to put props in setInterval inside `<CalculatorBuy />` but it just going to pass the same value again and again. My files:

```
index.js

export default function Home(props) {

  const {data} = props.result;

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Head>
        <title>Kup BTC</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></meta>
      </Head>
      <Header />

      <Main data={data}/>

      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const result = await coinGeckoClient.simple.price({
      ids: "bitcoin",
      vs_currencies: "pln",
  });
  return {
      props: {
          result
      },
  }
}
```

```
main.js

export default function Main(props) {
    const data = props.data;
    
    return (
        <main className="main">
                <div style={{ display: showMe?"block":"none" }}>
                    <Calculatorbuy data = {data} />
                </div>
        </main>
        )
}
```

```
calculatorbuy.js

export default function Calculatorbuy(props) {
    const data = props.data;
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
    const currentPrice = parseFloat(data.["bitcoin"].pln);
    console.log(currentPrice);
}
```

I would like to update the price in calculatorbuy every x seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getServerSideProps` will make Next.js to generate your page on the server-side on each request using the data returned by `getServerSideProps`. Your will only fetch the price on the server once per request.

If you need to have live price update, you can use `coinGeckoClient` in an interval using `setInterval` in `useEffect`.

Here is how you would fetch the price on the client-side but you can add an interval function to wrap the following easily.

````js
  const [price, setPrice] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPrice = async () => {
      const result = await coinGeckoClient.simple.price({
        ids: "bitcoin",
        vs_currencies: "pln",
      });
      setPrice(result);
    };
    fetchPrice();
  })```
````